# ¿Cómo saber el tamaño de una solicitud HTTP antes de que llegue a su destino?

Tags: nodejs, http, stream

Estoy estudiando nodejs y aprendí sobre streams y buffer. Lo encontré muy interesante porque se me ocurrió usarlo en un servidor HTTP, ya que si una solicitud es demasiado grande, los datos se pueden enviar poco a poco, especialmente cuando se usa el verbo POST para subir archivos grandes, como videos por ejemplo. El problema es que no todos los datos (archivos en este caso) son muy grandes. ¿Existe alguna manera de saber el tamaño de una solicitud antes de que llegue a su destino?

A mi se me ocurrió desde el cliente evaluar el tamaño del archivo antes de ser enviado y pasar el valor al servidor, pero no se si eso se puede hacer o si corro riesgo de performance. En caso de no ser posible ¿Existe alguna otro alternativa?

Comment: Adjunta tú código para que podamos ayudarte

Comment: @RimuruTempest no tengo código, solo quiero saber si existe alguna manera de saber el tamaño de una petición antes de que esta llegue al cliente. Pudiera ser con cualquier lenguaje, no tengo problemas con eso.

Comment: Quizás te interese esto https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32295689/how-to-get-byte-size-of-request/32296398

Comment: @RimuruTempest en ese caso la petición ya llegó.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const payloadLength = Buffer.byteLength( JSON.stringify( req.body ) );
```

De esta manera determino el tamaño en byte de la request